# Why this function called in the heap can't call cout?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, heap-memory

I was trying to call a function that was allocated in the heap. After some failed attempts I tried the code in this website:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/85d5da8c-edef-44b0-b42e-deb5f3eb2524

The code works flawlessly. It compiles, run, give the correct/expected result and finishes with no problem.

However if I try adding something like std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl in the function, copy it to the heap and then execute the heap function it just doesn't work. If there's a cout there it don't work, without the cout it works.

I would like to know why this happens, and how can I solve this problem. Realize that I am doing this with the only purpose of learning, I have no interest in applying this to the practical usage.

If I the heap function calls a function that uses std::cout to print data, that code doesn't work either.

Comment: I wouldn't attempt this, dragons may fly out your nose.

Comment: I am not afraid of that.

Comment: Aa I said, I don't intend to use it in real life. I will never do such thing. I just wanted to learn about new stuff, to get better knowledge of how some things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies with the fact that when you add the `cout` code to the function you essentially add some function calls. Microsoft C/C++ compiler uses some basic stack frame checking for detection of problems in runtime. Those checks are performed by calling the `__RTC_CheckEsp` function after each function call. The call to `__RTC_CheckEsp` uses the E8 opcode which means relative addressing. When the sample function is moved to the heap, the call to `__RTC_CheckEsp` becomes erroneous since it jumps to the wrong location.

Disable the runtime stack frame checking (in Visual Studio 2010): *Project options* -> *Configuration Properties* -> *C/C++* -> *Code Generation* -> *Basic Runtime Checks* -> set it to **Uninitialized Variables**

Recompile. Run. Enjoy!

Comment: Another option would be to compile this function as position independent code (PIC). Unfortunately the x86/x64 Win32 ABI does not support PICs and hence neither MSVC nor GCC/Win32 support PIC code on x86/x64 Windows (but both do on Itanium).

Comment: It doesn't work if you try to print strings like `cout << "asdasd"`: the `std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >` is called by relative call. I presume that is true for all template methods since they are not part of a library but created at compile time and thus are called by relative calls.

Answer (score 3):

In the article that you refer to, it states:

> Only use local variable, don't use global variable, static variable, and constant string variable.

But `std::cout` is a global. And I think that string literal would probably be classed as as "constant string variable" although the articles terminology is somewhat imprecise.

As others state the behavior of this code is undefined so exactly what happens is implementation specific. Different compilers may behave differently.

Comment: Is there a way to call static/global/constants value for a function in the heap to work with such data?

Comment: Maybe pass the globals etc as parameters to the function. But what is your real problem?

Comment: I have no real problem, I just want to learn about new stuff.

Comment: Have a look in the debugger, stepping through asm, to see how globals are referred to.

Answer (score 2):

You are relying on undefined behaviour here, and expecting it to do something sane.

If you want to know what's going "wrong" on your particular platform, I suggest using the debugger to step through the machine code.